# Flutter: async await

Tags: flutter

In the profile page of my app, I want to save a future list of objects from a firebase collection to a variable (myRecipes), using an async/await function. Depending on the outcome list, I want to display different widgets (using ifHasRecipes()) - if the list turns out to be null or empty, I want to display a text widget, otherwise I want to display the objects in the list using a listview builder (FavoritesHomePage class).

```
class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  List<Recipe> myRecipes;

  Future<List<Recipe>> getUserRecipes(UserData userData) async {
    return myRecipes = await DatabaseService().findUserRecipes(userData.uid);
  }

  Widget ifHasRecipes() {
    if (myRecipes != null && myRecipes != []) {
      return FavoritesHomePage(
          recipes: myRecipes, scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, title: 'Your recipes',);
    } else {
      return Text('You have no favorites yet');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
        stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            UserData userData = snapshot.data;
            getUserRecipes(userData);
            return Scaffold(
              body: SafeArea(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    //widgets using userData
                    ifHasRecipes(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                  child: SpinKitRipple(),),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

How can I make this code synchronized? I want to run the getUserRecipes() and when it's done, return different widgets depending on the outcome.

If I do a hot reload, the code "works" as I want it to, but sometimes when I navigate to this profile page via my pageview widget, the async/await function returning the variable myRecipes isn't done before the ifHasRecipes() is built, and then myRecipes is null (even though it shouldn't be)... Hope this isn't too confusing, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use a `FutureBuilder`, with this one you will have different states, just like the `StreamBuilder`, and you can show different widgets depending on the state, until the Future is resolved and you have the data.

I've done a little bit of refactoring to your code to make it work with the FutureBuilder, also I've changed it to Stateless, in this case it will display a `CircularProgressIndicator` until the Future is resolved, it will also handle errors and the lack of data.

```
class Profile extends StatelessWidget {
  const Profile({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<List<Recipe>> getUserRecipes(UserData userData) async {
    return await DatabaseService().findUserRecipes(userData.uid);
  }

  Widget ifHasRecipes(List<Recipe> myRecipes) {
    if (myRecipes != null && myRecipes != []) {
      return FavoritesHomePage(
        recipes: myRecipes,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        title: 'Your recipes',
      );
    } else {
      return Text('You have no favorites yet');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
      stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: getUserRecipes(snapshot.data),
                builder: (context, futureSnapshot) {
                  if (futureSnapshot.hasError)
                    return Text('Error: ${futureSnapshot.error}');
                  switch (futureSnapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.none:
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    case ConnectionState.active:
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    case ConnectionState.done:{
                      if (futureSnapshot.hasData) {
                        List<Recipe> myRecipes = futureSnapshot.data;
                        return Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            //widgets using userData
                            ifHasRecipes(myRecipes),
                          ],
                        );
                      }
                      return Text('There\'s no available data.');
                    }
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: SpinKitRipple(),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly! Never heard of FutureBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the code correctly, the solution is to rebuild the widget when the future is resolved by adding `setState((){});` to the `getUserRecipes()` method :

```
Future<void> getUserRecipes(UserData userData) async {
  myRecipes = await DatabaseService().findUserRecipes(userData.uid);
  setState((){});
}
```

(You don't have to return the value if you're assigning it to the state, but rather access it directly.)

By the way, you can use the **ternary operator** (or just regular conditions) to do conditional UI. Put this instead of `ifHasRecipes(),` :

```
(myRecipes != null && myRecipes != []) ?
  FavoritesHomePage(
          recipes: myRecipes, scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, title: 'Your recipes',)
  : Text('You have no favorites yet')
```

*If you get an error with this, increase your minimum SDK version to 2.6.0 in the pubspec.yaml*

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works! However this error also has to be fixed when using the pageview widget and your solution:

E/flutter (12544): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _HomePageState#2b9b0(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)

Comment: E/flutter (12544): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.

E/flutter (12544): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.

Comment: E/flutter (12544): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().